# How to call another function, if one function gives an error message

Tags: minibuffer, functions, error-handling

Suppose I call a function which is named as `foo`.

Sometimes that function `foo` will give a message such as `"Example of error message"`.  If that is the case, then something else should be executed.

This means that I need a way that to read the output of the messages buffer. 
In particular, I want to define a function `bar` that calls `foo` and executes something when `foo` gives a error:

```el
(defun bar () 
   (foo)
   (if (string-match `"Example of error message"` (minibuffer-output after calling foo))
           then do this)
      else do this thingy).
```

When I read the Emacs Documentation, I couldn't find anything that gives the functionality of reading the latest message from the minibuffer.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**SITUATION FROM THE REAL WORLD**:

It seems my post is not clear enough. I will detail it further from the actual situation here. I have the following:

```el
(defun foo () 
   (interactive)
   (evil-goto-mark ?8)
)
```

Calling the function `foo` produces the error `Marker 8' is not set in this buffer`.

If I get that message after calling `(evil-goto-mark ?8)`, I want to call `(evil-set-marker ?8)`  instead. The answer below didn't work in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to make it clear what you're asking.  The reference to abo-abo's answer in the very first line is particularly jarring.

Comment: abo-abo's answer should work for you. Try this function: `(defun foo () 
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil
      (evil-goto-mark ?8)
    (error (evil-set-mark ?8))))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in question is thrown with `user-error`, not simply echoed with `message`.

In your particular case testing the return value of `evil-get-marker` should work also:

```el
(if (evil-get-marker ?8)
  (evil-goto-mark ?8)
 (evil-set-marker ?8))
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant. I really appreciate it, thanks for that! I will try it soon. 
I didn't knew it was possible to get a false of true output from a function. How did you discover that?

Comment: I read the evil source; `evil-get-marker` is documented to return `nil` if there is no such marker, and `nil` is false.

Comment: Clever..  I marked your answer as the right one, because it solved my issue. Thanks for that!

Comment: It solves your problem, but does not answer the question :-) so strictly speaking it is not the correct answer...

Comment: Yes, it does not answer the question as posed. Rene: Please consider editing your question to reflect what you really wanted to know, so the answer fits the question better. That helps others looking for similar help.

Comment: @Drew, you're totally right. I changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 11):

No need to read `*Messages*`. Here's how error handling works in Elisp:

```cl
(defun bar ()
  (error "asdf"))

(defun foo ()
  (condition-case e
      (bar)
    (error
     (message "Caught an error: %S" e))))
```

Comment: I don't get it. 
Propably you switched `foo` and `bar` here? I would like to execute something in `foo`. And call `foo` from `bar`. and in `bar` something is executed when `foo` returns an error message.

Comment: Yes, I guess I switched it then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I modified it, but it's not working in my case. The problem is that `foo` will call another function, but I cannot modify it that it will return an error. I modified my opening post more, to be clear why.

Comment: Rene: You need to read the Elisp manual about handling errors - that's node [Handling Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html). I found that by: `C-h i`, choose Elisp manual, `i error S-SPC handl `  (using [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)). But even with vanilla Emacs it's not hard to find that node.

Answer (score 3):

If the function your are calling really echoes a message, you can use `(current-message)`.

> Return the string currently displayed in the echo area, or nil if
>   none.

Of course, it would be better to issue an error, see other answer for more details on this.